# Are Blastlocks not Special?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, warlock

I am making a character for D&D 5e and I am thinking about playing an Abjurer Eldritch Knight with a dip of Warlock for some refluffed flavor, out of combat utility, in combat utility, and I just kinda want to.

That said I realized something very bizarre during my reading. It seems that any character that just takes one level of warlock gets the Eldritch Blast and has it scale all game. Two levels gets two invocations which one could put into Agonizing blast and/or repelling blast and basically be a blast lock with only two levels of Warlock because as I read EB:

> "The spell creates more than one beam whenever you reach higher levels: two beams at 5th level, three beams at 11th level, and four beams at 17th level." PHB 237 - Eldritch Blast

[Anyclass]X + Warlock 2 = Blastlock

Granted one will lose out on a their 19th and/or 20th abilities, but they're still as blasty as a Blastlock. This seems to make the Blastlock kind of weak if everyone can take the Blastlock cake and eat it too.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## 2 levels of Warlock are enough for full Eldritch Blast damage

You are absolutely right, there is not much reason to go above level 2 with Warlock from an optimization standpoint, *if you only want Eldritch Blast.*

You get every benefit from [Eldritch Blast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46675/do-cantrips-use-your-character-level-or-class-level), without giving up much in return, since [cantrips scale with your character level, not your class level](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46675/9552). You will have to consider however  that Eldritch Blast requires Charisma, and that one is *the* usual dump stat of an Eldritch Knight. So you will either be quite bad at blasting, or sword swinging. Or both. There is no synergy in stats, playstyles, preferred distance, equipment, *nothing*.

### It is great for *others*

As every DnD edition with character options, 5E rewards specialization. You either excel at standing in the back rows and sniping enemies, or be a front liner. There is not much middle ground.
For a Sorcerer or Bard, 2 levels of Warlock is golden, to have a really strong cantrip when they run out of real spells. But not for a Fighter.

So **can** you take 2 levels of Warlock, for full Eldritch Blast progression? **Yes**
Is Eldritch Blast **worth** it from an optimization standpoint for a Fighter? **No**

### Other parts of Warlock might work better for *you*

However, if you do not focus on EB, Warlock can be a really good addition.

- Hex improves your DPR quite a bit, considering how many times a Fighter can attack on higher levels. Temporary hit points on a kill are also nice (Dark One's Blessing)
- 2 levels of Warlock double the number of slots per day, and you can get improved darkvision, even more hit points, or free Detect Magic (Invocations)
- 3 levels can give you quite a lot of great spells *not* belonging to the abjuration or evocation schools. Invisibility, Mirror Image, Phantasmal Force or Misty Step, all excellent for a Fighter

  - An invisible scout (Pact of Chain) or rituals (Pact of Tome)
- 4 levels give you an ASI
- 5 levels can give you Fireball, Stinking Cloud, Blink, Fear, Counterspell, or Vampiric Touch *and* an invocation
- 6 levels can give you a teleport+invisibility, Temporary Hit Points, or Advantage on an attack depending on your patron

### I would go like this:

- 1 Fighter level (saving throw/armor proficiencies)
- 2 Warlock levels (2 spell slots, 2 invocations, patron feature)
- 5 more Fighter levels (Extra Attack, ASI)
- 3 more Warlock levels (3rd level spells, 1 invocation, ASI, pact)
- Remaining levels in Fighter

Comment: *"For a Sorcerer or Bard, 2 levels of Warlock is golden"*... Well, silver maybe. As good a cantrip as it is, giving up two levels of bard or sorcerer advancement is a high cost — especially considering postponing ASI (or feat).

Comment: There are more Eldritch Blast related invocations in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, so a two-level dip is no longer "full Eldritch Blast progression".

Comment: @mattdm It's not a high cost for the sorcerer-- one level of pact magic is enough to decouple their spell slots from a daily reset cycle.  Short rests forever ftw!  Admittedly eldritch blast isn't the main deal, though.

Comment: Hi Andras, I've added in a link clarifying cantrips scale with character rather than class level, given a now-removed answer responding to that point (which you can see since you're 10k). If you think there's a better place or way to mention that, please be my guest to revise.

Comment: @mattdm you don't just get a _great_ cantrip, that does more damage than a sorcerer ever could with a cantrip, but it is with one of the best damage types. Also you get spell slots that come back per short rest, more spells known,  _better_ spells known _and_ patron features. If you worry about ASIs, just take Warlock 4.

Comment: @András Sure, if you are building a theoretical optimized level 20 character. If you're doing the standard thing of starting at level 1 and earning your levels through playtime, it's _definitely_ a significant cost.

Comment: @mattdm it is not just a theory, I had the opportunity to observe 5th level groups at an organized play event fight the same encounters. W2S3s were noticeably more effective than S5s