# What level is my multi-class character?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing

This is my build:

- Level 1 – Warlock 1 -  otherworldy patron, pact magic
- Level 2 – Warlock 2 -  eldritch invocations
- Level 3 – Warlock 3 -  pact boon
- Level 4 – Paladin 1 -  divine sense, lay on hands
- Level 5 – Paladin 2 -  fighting style, spell casting, smite

If I understand correctly I am character level 5 but class level 3 Warlock and class level 2 Paladin.

This means that Eldritch Blast will make 2 ranged attacks as I am character level 5, but I do not get an ability score improvement at level 4 because I get that at class level 4.

Is this correct?

EDIT: my players have started multi classing and this is an example character I made to try to understand the rules better.

The comment that Profecincy bonus used character level and not class level is the kind of information I was looking for.

I guess my question would be close to: using the build above what do I count as level 5 for?

Comment: Covered in [Multiclassing: How do Ability Score Improvements work?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46029/1204) and (less obviously) in [Are Blastlocks not special?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69126/1204) but we could probably do with a more definite canon question on that one.

Comment: You might want to edit your title as it doesn't cover what you specifically ask (how EB and ASI work with multiclassing?).

Comment: Technically this is 2 separate questions which are each a duplicate of another, but I don't think it's possible to indicate that in the close.

Comment: @doppelgreener May I point out that Proficiency Bonus is based on Character level and that this detail may be an included case for the querent?  Or is that a separate issue regarding Multi Class characters?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It's not what the question is about, anyway, and turning it from 2 questions into 3 questions is a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Miniman I see  your point.  Caveat: part of what makes multi classing a little confusing is that *level* applies to some subtly different things.  However, given the specificity requirements of a Good Question, I'll roll with your instinct on this.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast We have questions covering everything asked here, and I *think* there's one somewhere on proficiency, too.

Comment: @Miniman I was focusing on the question title, rather than on the textual inquiry that was focused on a cantrip, when I began to craft an answer (but it got closed as a dupe first).  Given the conflict between text and title, it is good that the closing action occurred.

Comment: @Miniman would it nort still be useful to have all those answers in one place so someone trying to learn the finess of the multi calssing rules does not have to search for them individually ?

Comment: @Skeith That's what the Player's Handbook is for.

Comment: Your edit makes the question "Please list everything affected by character level as opposed to class level." This is a too broad list question.

Comment: @Miniman TBH i got the answers i was looking for from the linked questions, im happy to roll back the edit or delete the question if you feel its just clutter

Comment: @Skeith Nah, closed questions are good because they'll help other people find the linked questions too.