# What is the caster level for the spells granted by Spell Sniper?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, cantrips

Cantrips generally get more powerful as you progress in your spellcasting class.

The *Spell Sniper* feat allows casting a cantrip.

If you pick a *Spell Sniper* cantrip from another class will the damage increase?
E.g.
  A level 6 Fighter takes the *Spell Sniper* feat and chooses *Produce Flame*. Would the damage be 1d8 or 2d8?

Comment: I searched before asking but didn't come across [Do Cantrips use your character level or class level?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46675/do-cantrips-use-your-character-level-or-class-level)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 2d8

Cantrips increase with your *character level*, which is independent of how many levels you have in spellcaster classes. If you are a multiclassed level 2 wizard, level 2 druid and level 2 cleric, you are a level 6 *character* for the purposes of Cantrip damage. The source of the Cantrip (spellcasting class, race, feat, etc) has no impact on this.

> **Cantrips**
> If a character has levels in more than one class, do the character’s cantrips scale with character level or with the level in a spellcasting class? Cantrips scale with character level. For example, a barbarian 2 / cleric 3 casts sacred flame as a 5th-level character. (Sage Advice Compendium V_2.0; page 11)