# If I am multiclassed with some levels of a caster class and some levels of a non-caster class, which spellcasting table do I use?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing

I'm creating a 10th level character which has 5 levels of Arcane Trickster Rogue and 5 levels of Drunken Master Monk. A 5th level ATR will have 3 1st level spell slots while the DMM has no slots.

When multiclassing, does my character keep using the regular [Arcane Trickster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/rogue#ArcaneTrickster) Spellcasting table on PHB page 98 since the DMM is not a caster, or do I need to use the [Multiclass Spellcasting table](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/customization-options#MulticlassSpellcaster) for a 5th level 1/3 caster only?  Does the Multiclass table only matter if you are using levels from multiple casters?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### You get spell slots as if you weren't multiclassed

This is explicitly stated in the [Multiclassing rules for Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting):

> Once you have the Spellcasting feature from more than one class, use the rules below. If you multiclass but have the Spellcasting feature from only one class, you follow the rules as described in that class.

Comment: Gah, I read that section multiple times but must have missed it every time.  Thank you!

Comment: It might be worth clarifying: If you are Arcane Trickster 5 and Drunken Master 5, you cast as an Arcane Trickster 5.

Comment: @Ethan Do scaling Cantrips follow the same reasoning?

Comment: @DanielZastoupil see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46675/41726) on cantrips

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you would follow the rules as described in that class.
If you were to pick up a level of wizard, for example, to augment your Arcane Trickster abilities, you must then use the Multiclass Spellcasting Table.

Some people like to take a level or two into Warlock, as the Pact-Magic spellcasting feature grants you 'warlock-spellslots.' You regain them after a short rest, and they increase (in slot level) with your warlock level; however, you can never have more than 4 of them.

Answer (score -5):

## There's no difference

Spellcasters all gain spells at the same rate, with 1/2 and 1/3 casters gaining them 1/2 and 1/3 as fast respectively. Compare the tables in the PHB for yourself.

Comment: There is a difference.  A level 4 arcane trickster rounds his levels *up* to determine spell slots.  A level 4 AT / level 1 cleric rounds his levels *down* in AT to determine spell slots.